# How do I install CACKey?

Tags: firefox

I am trying to install the CACKey to have my CAC be recognized by Firefox. I am used to windows guy, right click and install.

Anyone has detailed instructions on how to create the lib64 folder, and how or what extension I need to save. Tnhx...

Comment: I think this question isn't clear on the problem encountered, and so the answers don't address it. In case it is the same as what I encountered, I get an error message when I try to install the package: `unable to create `/usr/lib64/libcackey.so.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/lib64/libcackey.so'): No such file or directory`. So how is this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just install the Deb file from DISA's Forge.mil. Back when I had my CAC it worked just fine.

Then you need to go to (again this is from memory) the Firefox settings. Then the Advanced tab. Encryption sub-tab -> Security Devices. Then hit the Load button and name it whatever you'd like. Then for module filename, navigate to /usr/lib/libcackey.so (Hey, what do you know, I still have my CACkey security device...). Then hit OK. That's it! You may have to restart the browser to get it to load up right.

Admittedly, this was from a 32-bit install, but the process *should* be the same.

You will also need to install the pcscd package if you haven't already to get Ubuntu to recognize your card reader (I have a Gemalto Gem Plus that worked beautifully)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem and found a solution.

Distro was Mint Cinnamon, but I'm confident it will work for Ubuntu/Debian.

Go into root and manually create the /usr/lib64 folder.

Repeat installation, which should now be successful.

Best of luck.

Comment: creating directory lib64 solved installation problem :)

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot access DISA's Forge.mil website, (Because it requires CAC access)

You can Download the 32bit Deb file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8JoV2w_9hiceUoyeFBqSTV6a0U/edit?usp=sharing).
  
MD5: 37398d413221b7d6c6ee539978feec47
  
SHA1: 3ccfc97610b1b3503084caa7f1924c52d2f1a1b4

Or, the 64 bit Deb [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8JoV2w_9hicRGQ0TFQ5UEpwSkE/edit?usp=sharing).
  
 MD5: 3935d1376ae7175f9814505c59a917f7

SHA1: 153b30d025869679238444e2ef0545ed7185f4f8